# How to write to standard input in Elixir?

Tags: io, elixir

I have this module for checking the parity of numbers:

```
defmodule Parity do
  def start() do
    continue()
  end

  defp continue() do
    get_number()
    |> parse()
    |> even?()
    |> print_output()
    continue()
  end

  defp get_number() do
    IO.gets("Type a number: ")
  end

  defp parse(input) do
    String.trim(input)
    |> Integer.parse
  end

  defp even?({ number, _ }) do
    Integer.mod(number, 2) == 0
  end

  defp print_output(_is_even = true) do
    IO.puts("This number is even!")
  end

  defp print_output(_is_odd) do
    IO.puts("This number is odd!")
  end
end
```

And it works like this:

```
$ mix run -e Parity.start
Type a number: 4
This number is even!
Type a number: 3
This number is odd!
Type a number: 68
This number is even!
Type a number: 1
This number is odd!
Type a number: ...
```

Now I want to have another module, which would be able to **write numbers to the standard input** for the `Parity` module. So I need to have a something for executing `Parity.start()` and then providing numbers to `IO.gets()` function.
I tried something like this:

```
defmodule Bot do
  def start() do
    Parity.start()
    provide_number()
  end

  defp provide_number() do
    random_number()
    |> IO.puts
    provide_number()
  end

  defp random_number() do
    Enum.random(0..100)
  end
end
```

And it doesn't work.

It only starts `Parity` module, but there is no input from the `provide_number()` function.

Comment: You are running this all in a single thread. When you call `Bot.start/0`, it will call `Parity.start/0` which eventually calls `IO.gets/2`. Your program is now sitting and waiting for input and cannot continue code execution to the part where you are actually generating numbers.

Comment: What what purpose would you want to do this? Is it for testing purposes?

Comment: @RyanBigg I just want to simulate human input with another module.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**If you want to write to stdin** (like the equivalent of faking a CLI input) you pretty much need a way to exchange info between different system processes. [Porcelain](https://github.com/alco/porcelain) does that pretty well:

```
defmodule OtherModule do
  alias Porcelain.Process, as: Proc
  alias Porcelain.Result

  proc = %Proc{pid: pid} =
    Porcelain.spawn_shell("mix run -e Parity.start", in: :receive, out: {:send, self()})

  Proc.send_input(proc, "1")
  receive do
    {^pid, :data, :out, data} -> IO.inspect data   #=> "This number is odd!"
  end
end
```

Written without testing, but that should give you a rough idea. Porcelain has a *much* better handle on this than `System.cmd/3`. Alternatively, if you don't need **stdin**, you should run each module on their [own Elixir node](https://elixir-lang.org/getting-started/mix-otp/distributed-tasks-and-configuration.html):

```
iex --sname parity -S mix
```

Then in your `OtherModule` you can write something like:

```
pid = Node.spawn_link :"parity@computer-name", fn -> ... end
```